# Getting Syntax Error in Dictionary , want to understand the issue?

Tags: python-3.x

```
frameText = [{'font': 'arial', 'red': 255, 'green': 255, 'blue': 255, 'alpha': 255, 'text': 'MPC', 'posX': 0.0, 'posY': 0.03, 'align': 'left', 'size': 5, 'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.03}, {'font': 'arial', 'red': 255, 'green': 255, 'blue': 255, 'alpha': 255, 'text': '064_SOM_4400_v443', 'posX': 0.5, 'posY': 0.03, 'align': 'center', 'size': 5, 'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.03}, {'font': 'arial', 'red': 255, 'green': 255, 'blue': 255, 'alpha': 255, 'text': '08/12/23', 'posX': 1.0, 'posY': 0.03, 'align': 'right', 'size': 5, 'x': 1.0, 'y': 0.03}, {'font': 'arial', 'red': 255, 'green': 255, 'blue': 255, 'alpha': 255, 'text': '064_som_4400_pl02_v01_lfe_v1_work_roto', 'posX': 0.0, 'posY': 0.99, 'align': 'left', 'size': 5, 'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.99}, {'font': 'arial', 'red': 255, 'green': 255, 'blue': 255, 'alpha': 255, 'text': 'fL : %(focalLength)s', 'posX': 0.5, 'posY': 0.95, 'align': 'center', 'size': 5, 'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.95, 'metadataFn': <function getMetadataFn.<locals>.getStringReplacementDict at 0x7f5fa007c050>}, {'font': 'arial', 'red': 255, 'green': 255, 'blue': 255, 'alpha': 255, 'text': 'fD : %(focusDistance)s', 'posX': 0.6, 'posY': 0.95, 'align': 'center', 'size': 5, 'x': 0.6, 'y': 0.95, 'metadataFn': <function getMetadataFn.<locals>.getStringReplacementDict at 0x7f5fa00764d0>}, {'font': 'arial', 'red': 255, 'green': 255, 'blue': 255, 'alpha': 255, 'text': 'fS : %(fStop)s', 'posX': 0.4, 'posY': 0.95, 'align': 'center', 'size': 5, 'x': 0.4, 'y': 0.95, 'metadataFn': <function getMetadataFn.<locals>.getStringReplacementDict at 0x7f5f9f5dfc20>}, {'font': 'arial', 'red': 255, 'green': 255, 'blue': 255, 'alpha': 255, 'text': '(1029-1216)', 'posX': 0.97, 'posY': 0.99, 'align': 'right', 'size': 5, 'x': 0.97, 'y': 0.99}, {'font': 'arial', 'red': 255, 'green': 255, 'blue': 255, 'alpha': 255, 'text': '@FRAME#4@', 'posX': 1.0, 'posY': 0.99, 'align': 'right', 'size': 5, 'x': 1.0, 'y': 0.99}]
```

This is the dictionary , where i am getting syntax error unable to figure it out.
I want to know at which part it is giving syntax error?

Comment: Remove parts until you don't get an error anymore.

Comment: Please format your code, with a code block and line breaks, so it's more readable.

Comment: Also show the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the part which brakes it on three places.

`'metadataFn': <function getMetadataFn.<locals>.getStringReplacementDict at 0x7f5fa007c050>`

Either put it as string or create some object covering it. I would suggest a string version.

**EDIT:**
You cannot place something as a value which is unknown for your Python. Contrary to any other language such as `C#` you can have value of any `types` but the `type` has to exist!

Answer (score 0):

If you format your code you can easily find where the problem is. More so if you use a decent IDE.

```
frameText = [
    {
        "font": "arial",
        "red": 255,
        "green": 255,
        "blue": 255,
        "alpha": 255,
        "text": "MPC",
        "posX": 0.0,
        "posY": 0.03,
        "align": "left",
        "size": 5,
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.03
    },
    {
        "font": "arial",
        "red": 255,
        "green": 255,
        "blue": 255,
        "alpha": 255,
        "text": "064_SOM_4400_v443",
        "posX": 0.5,
        "posY": 0.03,
        "align": "center",
        "size": 5,
        "x": 0.5,
        "y": 0.03
    },
    {
        "font": "arial",
        "red": 255,
        "green": 255,
        "blue": 255,
        "alpha": 255,
        "text": "08/12/23",
        "posX": 1.0,
        "posY": 0.03,
        "align": "right",
        "size": 5,
        "x": 1.0,
        "y": 0.03
    },
    {
        "font": "arial",
        "red": 255,
        "green": 255,
        "blue": 255,
        "alpha": 255,
        "text": "064_som_4400_pl02_v01_lfe_v1_work_roto",
        "posX": 0.0,
        "posY": 0.99,
        "align": "left",
        "size": 5,
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.99
    },
    {
        "font": "arial",
        "red": 255,
        "green": 255,
        "blue": 255,
        "alpha": 255,
        "text": "fL : %(focalLength)s",
        "posX": 0.5,
        "posY": 0.95,
        "align": "center",
        "size": 5,
        "x": 0.5,
        "y": 0.95,
        "metadataFn": <function getMetadataFn..getStringReplacementDict at 0x7f5fa007c050>
    },
    {
        "font": "arial",
        "red": 255,
        "green": 255,
        "blue": 255,
        "alpha": 255,
        "text": "fD : %(focusDistance)s",
        "posX": 0.6,
        "posY": 0.95,
        "align": "center",
        "size": 5,
        "x": 0.6,
        "y": 0.95,
        "metadataFn": <function getMetadataFn..getStringReplacementDict at 0x7f5fa00764d0>
    },
    {
        "font": "arial",
        "red": 255,
        "green": 255,
        "blue": 255,
        "alpha": 255,
        "text": "fS : %(fStop)s",
        "posX": 0.4,
        "posY": 0.95,
        "align": "center",
        "size": 5,
        "x": 0.4,
        "y": 0.95,
        "metadataFn": <function getMetadataFn..getStringReplacementDict at 0x7f5f9f5dfc20>
    },
    {
        "font": "arial",
        "red": 255,
        "green": 255,
        "blue": 255,
        "alpha": 255,
        "text": "(1029-1216)",
        "posX": 0.97,
        "posY": 0.99,
        "align": "right",
        "size": 5,
        "x": 0.97,
        "y": 0.99
    },
    {
        "font": "arial",
        "red": 255,
        "green": 255,
        "blue": 255,
        "alpha": 255,
        "text": "@FRAME#4@",
        "posX": 1.0,
        "posY": 0.99,
        "align": "right",
        "size": 5,
        "x": 1.0,
        "y": 0.99
    }
]
```